# Save and continue training the LSTM network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I try to make a LSTM model continue were its last run left off. All compiles fine till I try to fit the network. Then it gives an error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_29 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (672, 1)

I checked various articles such as [this](https://jovianlin.io/saving-loading-keras-models/) and [this](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/)  but I don't see what is wrong in my code.

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential,Model
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Bidirectional, Input,Dropout,BatchNormalization
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras import initializers, regularizers, constraints

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model
import os.path
import os
filepath="Train-weights.best.hdf5"
act = 'relu'

model = Sequential()
model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=(10, 128)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0.5, activation=act, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

if (os.path.exists(filepath)):
   print("extending training of previous run")
   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
   with open('model_architecture.json', 'r') as f:
      model = model_from_json(f.read())
   model.load_weights(filepath)
else:
   print("First run")      
   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
   model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=100, batch_size=32, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=2)
   model.save_weights(filepath)
   with open('model_architecture.json', 'w') as f:
       f.write(model.to_json())

 checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
 callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

 model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=100, batch_size=32, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `model.summary()` and you would see that the output shape of last layer (i.e. the Dense layer) in the network is `(None, 10, 1)`. Therefore, the labels you provide to the model (i.e. `y_train`) must also have a shape of `(num_samples, 10, 1)`.

If the output shape `(None, 10, 1)` is not what you wanted (e.g. you want `(None, 1)` as the output shape of your model) then you need to modify your model definition. One simple modification to achieve that is removing the `return_sequences=True` argument from the LSTM layer.